# Declare generic Java class in an android project

Tags: java, android, class

i'm making a simple game for android and i need to declare a generic class to cast later in the code, i have 3 classes to chose from and they are chose dinamically, how can i achieve so?

```
enum difficulty {
    SIMPLE,
    MEDIUM,
    HARD
};

difficulty dif;

//assign dif

switch(dif) {
    case SIMPLE:
         ...
         break;
    case MEDIUM:
         ...
         break;
    case HARD:
         ...
         break;
}
```

it all depends on which of these gets chosen..

Comment: This is the same approach java used.

Comment: can you elaborate more?

Comment: i need to have a generic class to declare outside of the functions since i don't know which one will be called

Comment: First: Generics are for avoiding casts. Second: Generics don't work at runtime because of type ereasure. Thrid: I can't see anything to be solved with generics. Are you sure You are talking about generics?

Comment: you should look at the factory design pattern

Comment: for "generic" i mean something that can be converted into any class, for example: xxx newclass; newclass = new Simple();

Comment: Can you please check my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Create an `interface` or `abstract class` then `implements`(for `interface`)/ `extends`(for `abstract`) the parent class on the corresponding child classes.

e.g.

```
public interface IEasy{

}

public class EasyClassA implements IEasy{

}

public class EasyClassB implements IEasy{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps use a Difficulty base class and then extend from that a class for each of the 3 levels of difficulty, then in these classes set up stuff for the difficult level??

So like this:

```
public virtual DifficultyLevel
{

}

public EasyDifficulty extends DifficultyLevel
{
    // do stuff here to set difficulty to easy
}

public MediumDifficulty extends DifficultyLevel
{
    // do stuff here to set difficulty to medium
}
```

Then you can cast from a base type of DifficultyLevel to anything that inherits it :D

Comment: that's not java. Since the question has not the C++ tag you shouldnt put C++ code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your game simple, I don't see that you need to implement subclasses at all. If some behavior or logic (for example, a different AI, or boundary properties) changes between difficulties, then sure, subclass. But if it's just a matter of configuring some numbers (e.g., board size, movement speed, number of tries, physics constants), then just use 3 init functions or a `switch` like you do in the question.